# Differences between static constexpr and enum data member for storing non-type template parameter value in C++

Tags: c++, templates, enums, static, constexpr

In order to store a non-type template parameter inside the instance of a class, I often see either a `static constexpr` data member, or an `enum` declaration, as illustrated in the code below.

These two solutions seem equivalent when using them in simple case as in the `main()` function here.

This raises two questions:

**1.** Is there any operation we can do with one solution that we cannot do with the other?

**2.** Which versions of C++ allow or forbid these solutions?

```
#include <iostream>

// solution 1
template<int _i>
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr int i = _i;
};

// solution 2    
template<int _i>
struct Bar
{
    enum 
    {
        i = _i
    };
};

int main()
{ 
    Foo<1> foo;
    Bar<2> bar;

    std::cout << foo.i << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar.i << std::endl;

    std::cout << Foo<3>::i << std::endl;
    std::cout << Bar<4>::i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `constexpr` is available since C++11

Comment: I think the question is unfortunately too broad, as it's asking for a list of differences of two language constructs across all versions of C++.